# signed apk not display google map after change SH1 key

Tags: android, google-maps, sign

I am creating a signed APK with updated version. i.e already having version 6 on play store.
up to this all is ok and google map is display property.Now, in update-Version 7 my SH1 key changed as PC changed... I created new API key for google map and it display proper google map in debug APK. but not display in signed APK(yet not uploaded version 7 on play store) for this issue what i can do? i got idea that SH1 key should be upload on App signing certificate but not knowing how and when i can change it. please guide[image: app signing]

Comment: If you have used google play app signing then your SHA-1 certificate gets changed from which you have added in google developer console. So now what you have to do is add App Signing SHA-1 as in above pic to your project in google developer console.

Comment: @mohammed Fahan how i can edit or can add new one?

Comment: @ Android User, just add App Signing `SHA1` key to `google developer console`, and test it.

Comment: @nirav how can i change  SH1 ? i mean it is not editable in above screen shot

Comment: @AndroidUser, not edit , just add in play console, refer the image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhFb9.png)

Answer (score 3):

For signed apk you need to put SHA-1 which is already generated by google play console. In your screen shot there is certificate SHA-1 , you need to add that certificate in google developer console after than download the latest google.json file & create new build and upload on play store. 
Hope , it will work fine for you.

Comment: You need to just copy your sha1 from google play console & paste it on google developer console (where you have made your project for map integration) and after than download google.json file & put that json file into your project